# Count number of values inside a timeperiod that are lower to threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a DataFrame with the following configuration:

```
                            data    mov_avg
Timestamp       
2019-12-02 00:00:00-05:00   1.0    1.0
2019-12-03 00:00:00-05:00   1.0    1.0
2019-12-04 00:00:00-05:00   1.0    1.0
2019-12-05 00:00:00-05:00   1.0    1.0
2019-12-06 00:00:00-05:00   1.0    1.0
... ... ...
2022-06-21 00:00:00-04:00   1.0    1.0
2022-06-22 00:00:00-04:00   1.0    1.0
2022-06-23 00:00:00-04:00   1.0    1.0
2022-06-24 00:00:00-04:00   1.0    1.0
2022-06-25 00:00:00-04:00   1.0    1.0
```

Most `data` values are equal to 1, and I'm trying to find periods where:

- `mov_avg` is lower than 1 for more than X timestamps (e.g. X=7)

**AND**

- There are at least Y values in `data` lower than 1 (e.g. Y=5)

I managed to get the first of the two conditions via the following code:

```py
# Create a column for timestamps that have mov_avg lower than 1
df['pos_out'] = df['mov_avg'] < 1

# Create 'cons_day_out' column that return # of consecutive days with mov_avg lower than 1
g = df['pos_out'].ne(df['pos_out'].shift()).cumsum()
df['cons_days_out'] = df.groupby(g)['pos_out'].transform('size') * np.where(df['pos_out'], 1, 0)

# Return 'True' for periods with more than 7 days with mov_avg lower than 1
min_out_days = 7
df['out_cond1'] = (df['cons_days_out'] > min_out_days)
```

but I can't find a way to check for the other condition.

***EDIT***: Snippet with dict to reproduce dataset [here](https://gist.github.com/ajossorioarana/d5def0195959f42e8a6ecbcfe9bb86aa)

Comment: please post a dictionary so we can reproduce the data set easily. Example: print(df.to_dict())

Comment: Thanks for the response! Edited the question with the dict snippet

Comment: Do you want moving windows to be based on a date range (eg 7 days) or a count of timestamps (eg 7 timestamps).   It is not clear if these are equivalent from your data.

Comment: @Riley In this case, the timestamps are daily. The condition could be "7+ consecutive days with `mov_avg` less than 1, where there are 5+ `data` values lower than 1 (consecutive or not)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is going to use [`staircase`](https://www.staircase.dev) which is package part of the pandas ecosystem for working with step functions.

We'll turn your time series data into step functions - piecewise constant functions which changes value whenever your time series changes value.

Since the timestamps are daily, the time component is not really relevant here.  We can just work with the index of timestamps on the x-axis.

We can create step functions from the data like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import staircase as sc

sf_data = sc.Stairs.from_values(
    initial_value=0,
    values=df["data"].reset_index(drop=True),
)

sf_mov_avg = sc.Stairs.from_values(
    initial_value=0,
    values=df["mov_avg"].reset_index(drop=True),
)
```

We'll also clip the step functions at 0 and the `len(df)` (=937) since this is the region we're interested in

```
sf_data = sf_data.clip(0,len(df))
sf_mov_avg = sf_mov_avg.clip(0,len(df))
```

Let's plot `sf_mov_avg` so you can see what the idea is

```
sf_mov_avg.plot()
```

[image]

The `sf_mov_avg` object is of type `staircase.Stairs`.  This is to the staircase library what Series is to pandas - it's the main workhorse.  You can compare them, add them, multiply them etc. We can find out where it is less than 1 by simply doing `sf_mov_avg < 1` which gives us back a boolean valued step function - it will be 1 everywhere it is true, and 0 otherwise.  We can explore the step function in dataframe form using `to_frame`:

```
(sf_mov_avg < 1).to_frame()
```

which gives us the following pandas dataframe

```
  start  end value
0  -inf    0   NaN
1     0  456     0
2   456  464     1
3   464  714     0
4   714  733     1
5   733  937     0
6   937  inf   NaN
```

We're only interested in those parts where the step function has value of 1 - but also where the intervals are strictly greater than 7, so let's identify those

```
cond1 = (sf_mov_avg < 1).to_frame().query("value == 1").query("end - start > 7")
```

`cond1` looks like this

```
  start  end value
2   456  464     1
4   714  733     1
```

From here let's convert these intervals (which satisfy your first condition) to a pandas interval index:

```
cond1_intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(cond1["start"], cond1["end"], closed="left")
```

Next we'll create a boolean step function for whenever `sf_data` is less than 1, then we'll slice the step function by those intervals satisfying the first condition, then integrate.  Since the step function is 0-1 valued, integrating tells us how many days are "true" (with respect to second condition).

```
cond2_candidates = (sf_data < 1).slice(cond1_intervals).integral()
```

`cond2_candidates` looks like this

```
[456, 464)    2
[714, 733)    5
dtype: int32
```

As you can see there is an interval with two days where df["data"] is less than 1, and another with 5 days.  Filter, and pull out intervals where condition 2 is satisfied like so:

```
cond2_intervals = cond2_candidates[cond2_candidates >= 5].index
```

This gives you a pandas interval index

```
IntervalIndex([[714, 733)], dtype='interval[int64, right]')
```

Let's look at the original data between these index values for the first (and only) interval in this interval index

```
df.iloc[cond2_intervals[0].left: cond2_intervals[0].right]
```

which gives

```
                               data   mov_avg
2021-11-15 00:00:00-05:00  1.000000  0.976190
2021-11-16 00:00:00-05:00  1.000000  0.833333
2021-11-17 00:00:00-05:00  1.000000  0.833333
2021-11-18 00:00:00-05:00  0.833333  0.833333
2021-11-19 00:00:00-05:00  0.000000  0.809524
2021-11-20 00:00:00-05:00  1.000000  0.666667
2021-11-21 00:00:00-05:00  1.000000  0.666667
2021-11-22 00:00:00-05:00  0.833333  0.690476
2021-11-23 00:00:00-05:00  0.000000  0.833333
2021-11-24 00:00:00-05:00  1.000000  0.833333
2021-11-25 00:00:00-05:00  1.000000  0.833333
2021-11-26 00:00:00-05:00  1.000000  0.857143
2021-11-27 00:00:00-05:00  1.000000  0.857143
2021-11-28 00:00:00-05:00  1.000000  0.857143
2021-11-29 00:00:00-05:00  1.000000  0.857143
2021-11-30 00:00:00-05:00  0.000000  0.857143
2021-12-01 00:00:00-05:00  1.000000  0.857143
2021-12-02 00:00:00-05:00  1.000000  0.857143
2021-12-03 00:00:00-05:00  1.000000  0.857143
```

You should be able to see that this section of the data satisfies your conditions.

In general we can filter the dataframe to include only the relevant data like so:

```
df[cond2_intervals.contains(range(len(df)))]
```

**summary**

```
sf_data = sc.Stairs.from_values(
    initial_value=0,
    values=df["data"].reset_index(drop=True),
)

sf_mov_avg = sc.Stairs.from_values(
    initial_value=0,
    values=df["mov_avg"].reset_index(drop=True),
)

sf_data = sf_data.clip(0,len(df))
sf_mov_avg = sf_mov_avg.clip(0,len(df))

cond1 = (sf_mov_avg < 1).to_frame().query("value == 1").query("end - start > 7")
cond1_intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(cond1["start"], cond1["end"], closed="left")
cond2_candidates = (sf_data < 1).slice(cond1_intervals).integral()
cond2_intervals = cond2_candidates[cond2_candidates >= 5].index
results = df[cond2_intervals.contains(range(len(df)))]
```

note: I am the author of `staircase`, feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't knew about `staircase` package.  Definetively will use it in a number of projects.